# jsforce-ajax-proxy always runs into timeout on Update and Create

Tags: rest-api, jsforce

Im using jsForce to communicate with salesforce from my web app. The app has a node.js based webserver where I included jsforce-ajax-proxy to circumvent CORS issues.
Querying works fine but if I try to make an update or create the call always fails with a timeout.

I included the jsforce-ajax-proxy as express.js middleware in my server code as follows:

```
app.all("/proxy/?*", jsforceAjaxProxy({ enableCORS: true }));

// load tasks
app.get("/api/infos", function (req, res) {
    // additional server dode
});
```

When I change the proxyUrl-parameter in the `jsforce.browser.init` call from my proxy-address to https://node-salesforce-proxy.herokuapp.com/proxy/ I can make updates and creates. But since this url is not under my control I want to use my own proxy.

Any ideas if I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I did wrong. It seems that `app.all("/proxy/?*", jsforceAjaxProxy({ enableCORS: true }))` must be placed before other `app.use` statements. Now that I placed it on the top everything works like a charm.